# Recursive function for finding same numbers on same positions between two arrays

Tags: c, function, recursion

Here is an example of what the result should be :

1234 and 1344 Have two numbers on same positions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Proverka(int *num1[], int *num2[], int len, int pom) 
{   
    if (len < 1 && pom < 1)
        return 0;
    if (*num1 == *num2)
        return 1 + Proverka(num1++, num2++, len-1, pom-1);
    else {
        return Proverka(num1++, num2++, len-1, pom-1);
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int *num1[5], *num2[5], pom, len, i, sin, j;

    pom = sizeof(num1) / sizeof(num1[0]);
    len = sizeof(num2) / sizeof(num2[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < pom; i++) {
        printf("Enter elements for first array :");
        scanf("%d", num1[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < len; j++){
        printf("Enter elements for second array : ");
        scanf("%d", num2[j]);
    }

    sin = Proverka(num1, num2, pom, len);

    {
        printf("They have %d numbers on same positions", sin);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @G.Samaras It's there.

Comment: Your code is annoying to look at, please indent it properly, it's really bad to get used to writing code like that, it's good advice, just fix it.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: I have formatted it. Don't you guys mess it up with another edit.

Comment: @theAlias It's not working , and i need an idea on how to make it work .

Comment: And your code works, or it doesn't what is your question?

Comment: I'd start by fixing the *undefined behavior* you're invoking in `main()`. You're scanning values into indeterminate memory locations. None of the pointers in those pointer arrays are established at the time of the scans. That in itself makes your program ill-formed. Fix it.

Comment: @iharob it doesn't , so if we can fix it , or make a short version of it? :D

Comment: I think the `len < 1 && pom < 1` part should be `len < 1 || pom < 1` but just guessing here.

Comment: @MightyPork You are right , my mistake :D

Comment: Now that I look closer, *all* of the arrays in this are incorrectly declared to house pointers rather than data.

Comment: @WhozCraig What is the correct way to declare them?

Comment: @Lolapanza as `int` arrays, not `int*` arrays. theAlias says as-much below.

Comment: check my answer, I tested int in gcc and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a lot of bugs in the code, here's a working version of it.

Read comments to understand what I changed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Proverka(int *num1, int *num2, int len1, int len2)
{
    if (len1 < 1 && len2 < 1) return 0;
    // note the pre-increment. Your post-increment wouldn't have worked. Or just add 1.
    return (*num1 == *num2) + Proverka(++num1, ++num2, len1 - 1, len2 - 1);
    // this works, since "boolean" is really just 0 or 1
}

int main (void)
{
    // I make array of ints, not of pointers to ints.
    int num1[5], num2[5], len1, len2, i, same;
    len1 = sizeof(num1) / sizeof(num1[0]);
    len2 = sizeof(num2) / sizeof(num2[0]);

    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        printf("First array element %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num1[i]); // pointer at the element
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len2; i++){
        printf("Second array element %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &num2[i]);
    }

    // get pointers at the first array elements
    same = Proverka(&num1[0], &num2[0], len1, len2);
    printf("They have %d numbers on same positions\n", same); // newline - good practice
    return 0;
}
```

Here's a bit more "optimized" and cleaned up version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ITEMS 5

int Proverka(const int *aa, const int *bb, const int len)
{
    if (len == 0) return 0;
    return (*aa == *bb) + Proverka(1 + aa, 1 + bb, len - 1);
}

int main (void)
{
    int aa[ITEMS], bb[ITEMS], i, same;

    for (i = 0; i < ITEMS; i++) {
        printf("First array element %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &aa[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < ITEMS; i++) {
        printf("Second array element %d:", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &bb[i]);
    }

    same = Proverka(&aa[0], &bb[0], ITEMS);
    printf("They have %d numbers on same positions\n", same);
    return 0;
}
```

Using recursion for this is not a very good choice, a loop would be easier and safer. But this works too - for not-too-large arrays.

Comment: Since you noted it, so shall I. Note the pre increment isn't even needed. There is no need to persist this values to `num1` and `num2`prior to invoking the recursion. `num1+1` and `num2+1` are sufficient.

Comment: Yeah I didn't really bother with optimizing, it'd only confuse the OP. You should be able to make all the arguments const, I guess.

Comment: Thanks alot, all mighty pork! Hmm i guess i was close .. somehow. :D Why do you return (*num1=*num2) ?

Comment: @WhozCraig check my second version, any mistakes in this one?

Comment: @Lolapanza if they are equal, you get 1, otherwise 0. It's the same thing you did with your ifs, just much shorter. Maybe it'd be better to use `(*aa == *bb ? 1 : 0)` to ensure it's 1, since True is generally anything nonzero. But it seems to work like this.

Comment: @MightyPork Now this is just orgasmic. Thanks alot dude . :)

Answer (score 1):

int *num1[5],*num2[5] ... doesnt give you an array of integer pointers with memory allocated. Fix that. Allocate memory using malloc.

Or just say `int num1[5],num2[5]` and `scanf("%d",&num1[i]);`